# How can create php custom funtion for get All USER ON ROLE Base (Vtlib Function) from my CRM vtiger 7

Tags: php, vtiger

I hope all of you are doing well.,
How can create php custom funtion for get All USER ON ROLE Base (Vtlib Function) from my CRM vtiger 7.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple functions defined in "include/utils/UserInfoUtil.php" to fulfill your requirements. One of the functions from the list below will help you get the required data.

1. getRoleUsers
2. getRoleUserIds
3. getRoleAndSubordinateUsers
4. getSubordinateRoleAndUsers